# LibreOffice 3.5.72 - non printing characters

Tags: libreoffice

I am trying to visualize non printing characters on LibreOffice 3.5.7.2 Build ID: 350m1(Build:2) in Ubuntu 12.04

According to the help page and to what I have found on line, I should either press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> or go to Tools - Options - LibreOffice Writer/LibreOffice Writer/Web - Formatting Aids

As an other alternative, I could modify the  standard bar (adding the desired tool).

The problem is that none of these is available! No relevant icon in the standard bar, no LibreOffice Writer in the options, no function linked to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>!

Am I doing it wrong? Do I need to update Libre Office?
Edit: Hi, Vasa1, the tool was installed by default. I will have a look at other posts regarding the menus and see if updating it solved the issue.

Comment: Missed the top of the post:
Missed the top of the post:
Hy, Guys,
etc...

Comment: Where did you get this software from? Was it from the Ubuntu Software Center or was it installed by default (as it should)? If I remember correctly, there have been some issues with LibreOffice menus not behaving well in some Ubuntu DEs.